# Configuring MySQL fails with service not starting (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, mysql

I am trying to use `Mysql5.5.30-win32`. I installed it and run the configure wizard and see that at the final page my wizard hangs when trying to start mysqld service.

I tried starting mysqld manually and it says

`InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 54525952 bytes InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 115343360 bytes!". Then i tried changing the innodb_log_file_size in my.ini to 52M (==54525952) and start manually again`.

Now it starts, but if i run the configuration wizard, the same problem is faced coz the configuration wizard overwrites my **my.ini** file and changes the value of **innodb_log_file_size**.

How to i solve this? I tried uninstalling mysql and completely deleting the mysql folder, but the problem still persist.

Moreover I am not able to locate any **ib_logfile0** anywhere in my **mysql5.5** folder. So where is this 54525952 value taken from?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Actually the ib_logfile0 was available within the C:\Progsql seramData\Mysql folder and C:\ProgramData was a hidden folder.. Removing the ib_logfile* files and configuring the mysql service works fine..